# Cloud ConsoleRedirection Not Working

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm using Console.WriteLine in a Guest Executable service.

I enabled ConsoleRedirection as instructed [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app/#set-up-logging) and am able to see logs locally.

When I log into the Cloud VM I see the log files, but they are empty.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the process is still running and has not flushed the buffers?